# GoogleApiClient in non-fragment activity

Tags: android, google-api-client

I am trying to get google Sign-In working in my app but I don't understand how to use `GoogleAPIClient`. I have made instance in  my Sign-In activity but how do I use it elsewhere? For example,I have my menu activity (normal Activity not Fragment) and I want to use `GoogleAPIClient` in it. How can I do that? Can I make more instances of GoogleAPIClient or make one that is static?
I use constructor from Google tutorials:

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .build();
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this, this)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();
```

Thanks for answer. 
~BeefEX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that its for the sign-in and that sign-in is a crucial part of almost every app that deals with it. I suggest you to keep things simple.

Create a `SignInActivity` or something similar and place that snippet there. Whenever sign-in is required just point your app to that `SignInActivity`. And then, if you acquire any information that you need, just keep it in-memory or store it in disk (`Application` instance, `SharedPreferences`, etc.) and then refer to that instead.

This way you'll have a central sink to your app flow that deals with the sign-in and there will be no duplications minus the complication that could have surfaced if you have had to duplicate logic or different sort of flow.